# Elasticsearch won't start and no logs centOS

Tags: elasticsearch, installation, file-access

Hi after downloading the latest rpm for CentIS and and installing for the first time I am getting this error in the logs:

```
Jun 22 09:47:31 ssd316r.simpleservers.co.uk systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
Jun 22 09:47:32 ssd316r.simpleservers.co.uk systemd-entrypoint[2501]: ERROR: Temporary file directory [/usr/share/elasticsearch/tmp] does not exist or is not accessible
Jun 22 09:47:32 ssd316r.simpleservers.co.uk systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a
Jun 22 09:47:32 ssd316r.simpleservers.co.uk systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
Jun 22 09:47:32 ssd316r.simpleservers.co.uk systemd[1]: Unit elasticsearch.service entered failed state.
Jun 22 09:47:32 ssd316r.simpleservers.co.uk systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service failed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is due to below log:

> Jun 22 09:47:32 ssd316r.simpleservers.co.uk systemd-entrypoint[2501]:
> ERROR: Temporary file directory [/usr/share/elasticsearch/tmp] does
> not exist or is not accessible

Can you check `/usr/share/elasticsearch/tmp` is present on your server or not, if not please create this folder at the same location and make sure your elasticsearch process has write access to it.

Comment: Hello .. it does not exist... i can create it... but can you give me some help how to make sure my elasticsearch process has write access????

Comment: @MattAyres how you are running the elasticsearch process? you can read about https://linuxize.com/post/linux-chown-command/ on how to see and change the ownership

Comment: I am trying to start the elastic search service .. as root

Comment: @MattAyres any luck ?

Comment: @MattAyres let me know if you need further help, looking forward to hear from you

Comment: @MattAyres any luch, it would be great if you can provide the update.

Comment: Yes I sorted it by simply creating the tmp dir and giving elastic search user write permissions.